# Swipe tabs vertically in CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

```java
Tabs mainUI = new Tabs(Component.BOTTOM);
mainUI.setUIID("Tabs");
mainUI.hideTabs();    
....
```

How can we swipe containers using tabs vertically in CodenameOne ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabs have been hardcoded for side swipe, they don't support up/down swipe due to some builtin assumptions in the `Tabs` e.g. reliance on a layout that arranges the underlying container one next to the other etc.

You have several options. Just use scrolling and define the snap to grid value to take up the entire screen this will effectively provide you with the ability to scroll as a swipe.

You can also use a List or just use the code from `Tabs` as a reference to create a vertically swipeable component.